# How could Apple know that an iPhone app makes use of hidden API?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wonder if they have any fancy tools that detect usage of hidden API. Does anyone know?

Comment: I often use 1-2 private methods in my apps And apple didn't reject them

Answer (score 1):

In my experience unless you do something that really makes Apple mad, it isn't going to be rejected. If you were to do something huge, like getting direct camera access to make a video recorder app, it would obviously be rejected.

But if you were to use something small that isn't directly visible, it probably won't get rejected.

No one can really say for sure, because Apple seems to randomly reject apps for various reasons.

Don't make and entire app based off of a Private API, because you will have spent a ton of time and Apple may or may not reject it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing they do is look at the app's link tables.

Comment: could anyone look at these? how?